# How to handle different namespaces in OPCUA Server using c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, opc-ua

I have developed OPCUA Server Application using CSharp .net
I am maintaining two Namespaces inside Namespace.cs like

```cs
public const string Demo = "http://demo.demo1/Demo1";
public const string Demo2 = "http://demo.demo2/Demo2";
```

I want to pass above namespaces in Demo1 configuration class according to our different `OPCUA Server` projects without creating separate configuration class and Node Manager class.

Currently Namespace attribute accepting only constant `[DataContract(Namespace = Namespaces.Demo)]` so how to handle this.